# Facebook API for Android displays blank window

Tags: android, facebook, webview, android-webview

I am using the Facebook API to post messages to Facebook from my Android app. I have tested it out on various different phones, yet on one particular phone the Facebook API just pops up a blank white dialogue window that doesn't load the FB log in page.

I have tested it on the Samsung Galaxy S, the HTC Desire, HTC Sensation and it works fine - but when I try it on the HTC Wildfire S it does not work.

There are no messages popping up in LogCat and stepping through it with the debugger does not reveal any problems.

Looking through the code provided by Facebook I can see it is just a WebView which is being created. There is a function called onPageFinished(..) which gets called but there is nothing in the WebView.

I'm not really sure what to try to fix this. I've tried clearing some settings on the phone but that did not work. Does anybody have any ideas?

Comment: Should be noted that the hash key is correct, as is the app key so that's not an issue. (I'm on the same dev team)

Comment: I have seen this a few times. Usually when it happened to me, something went wrong with the site encryption. In this case a warning got thrown into the logcat, indicating some SSL error/exception and the page stayed blank. Not sure which tag the warning had. Sorry for beeing vague, it's been a while. Maybe check the facebook sdk codebase and see how it handles ssl-(certificate)errors. Never found a way to fix it myself though.

Comment: Thank you. The date on the phone was set to some day in 1980 and this was messing up validating the SSL for loading up Facebook. Simply changed the phones date and it worked fine.